# Ubuntu 12.10 purple screen with AMD X1300 Mobility graphics card (can boot with nomodeset or radeon.modeset=0)

Tags: ati

A new ubuntu user here and i've just installed it on an older laptop of mine with the above graphics card; and ati x1300 mobility.

I have a dual boot setup with windows xp.

my issue is that I cannot boot normally without pressing E in the grub menu and adding either nomodeset or radeon.modeset=0 in place of quiet and splash.

When i do load after this, the display is quite laggy. I've looked around but I am at a loss with what i do; i've gathered that there are

1. ati drivers
2. fglrx drivers
3. xorg drivers

and apparently the only ones that work for my series of card is the xorg drivers. so i did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

as per this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723067

but when i restarted it didn’t help and i still got the purple screen. Im not sure i installed correctly

I've also tried installing fglrx and then subsequently purging it because it didint work.

As an addendum to that, fglrx got me past the blank purple screen but i it stalled with:
"The system is running in low-graphics mode your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected" and froze on that screen."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
regards

Answer (score 0):

well, does not matter what you will do, amd closed support for "old" devices and drivers are not updated to work with xorg 1.13 and kernel 3.5.

the only solution is to "follow instructions on this page :: at your own risk"

http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a Linux Kernel issue, and has been since kernel version 3.5. I have also been experiencing it -.-

The only thing to do is go to something using an older kernel (like 12.04 LTS) and find some way to contact the ones behind the Linux Kernel to see of they can fix it.